# Trouble with understanding equals method in Java

Tags: java, object

I'm learning Java from mooc course and I have problem with understanding this example of writing method that will be comparing objects:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int age;
private int weight;
private int height;

// constructors and methods


public boolean equals(Object compared) {
    // if the variables are located in the same position, they are equal
    if (this == compared) {
        return true;
    }

    // if the compared object is not of type Person, the objects are not equal
    if (!(compared instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }

    // convert the object into a Person object
    Person comparedPerson = (Person) compared;

    // if the values of the object variables are equal, the objects are equal
    if (this.name.equals(comparedPerson.name) &&
        this.age == comparedPerson.age &&
        this.weight == comparedPerson.weight &&
        this.height == comparedPerson.height) {
        return true;
    }

    // otherwise the objects are not equal
    return false;
}

// .. methods
}
```

Despite it being commented upon each step, I don't understand the fact that the method keeps going after

```
 if (!(compared instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }
```

So, if "compared" isn't Person type object it returns false, so the method should just stop working, but then there are instructions that enable making it the same type of object that we're comparing it with. Can somebody explain to me, how is it possible that after returning false, the object with "wrong" type can be converted and compared despite not satysfying condition above, which should result in ending the method?

Comment: "how is it possible that after returning false..." after returning anything, nothing more in the method executes. The stuff after the `return false` only executes if the condition was false, i.e. it *is* an instance of `Person`.

Comment: Either the given object is not an instance of Person, in which case the method returns false; or the object *is* an instance of Person, and the method goes on to check its fields for equality with `this`.

Comment: The misleading thing is the comment "convert the object into a Person object" above  `Person comparedPerson = (Person) compared;` This is *not* converting the object to a Person. It is *casting* the object (which is actually a Person) to a reference of type Person so we can check its Person-specific properties. If the object was not already an instance of Person, this would cause a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Compared`is not a `Person` the method returns `false`(i.e. not equal) and finishes.
But if you call `equals` with an object of type `Person` the condition is not met and the method does not return false but continues. And if that happens we know `compared`must be of type `Person`. But the compiler doesn't know that (it could if it was smarter, but it isn't). So the line

```
Person comparedPerson = (Person) compared;
```

does not 'convert' anything. The comment is misleading. This typecast just tells the compiler our object is in fact of type `Person`. And this allows the following code to use it as a Person and call Person methods.